# Using Cuda to add pointer arrays. Only the first value is correct

Tags: pointers, cuda

I'm following a intro to CUDA parallel programming tutorial and I'm having some difficulty getting valid answers.

Tutorial -> http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-cuda-c-basics.pdf

My code, posted below, which is similar to the tutorial, compiles and runs however only the first integer of the array is correctly calculated.

It appears that there is some sort of a data alignment problem, I just don't understand why. Also, I have never seen mathematical operations done on an array in this fashion (adding without indices and relying on the block size to define the bit boundaries).
I understand why it would work, and it works in the tutorial, so I assume I have overlooked something.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
  *c = *a + *b;
} 

int main(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int n = 100;
  int size = n * sizeof(int);

  int* inputA;
  int* inputB;
  int* output;

  int* d_inputA;
  int* d_inputB;
  int* d_output;

  inputA = (int*)malloc(size);  
  inputB = (int*)malloc(size);
  output = (int*)malloc(size);

  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_inputA, size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_inputB, size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, size);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    inputA[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    inputB[i] = rand() % 500 +1;
  }

  cudaMemcpy(d_inputA, inputA, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_inputB, inputB, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  add<<<n,1>>>(d_inputA, d_inputB, d_output);

  cudaMemcpy(output, d_output, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  std::cout << i << ": "
    << inputA[i] << " + " << inputB[i] << " = "
    << output[i] << std::endl;
  }
  free(inputA);
  free(inputB);
  free(output);

  cudaFree(d_inputA);
  cudaFree(d_inputB);
  cudaFree(d_output); 

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have written it, every thread in the kernel will be performing the equivalent of

```
__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
  c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
}
```

which should make it apparent why only the first element of the array has the correct value.

If you modify the kernel like this:

```
__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
  c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
}
```

So that each thread in the 1D grid computes a unique index, you should find the kernel does what you are expecting. The index is calculated using built in variables which you will find a discussion of if you read on in the introductory material you are using (e.g. up through slide 26).

Comment: That makes sense.  I saw that but forgot to make those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel only reads and writes to the first element of the array, so that's what you get in the output...

Perhaps you're mistakenly assuming that different threads would get different pointers - to consecutive elements of the arrays? Well, that's not how CUDA works. Every thread gets the exact same parameters, and they only differ by their thread and block identifiers:

```
__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

This should do it in the general case. In your case, you have 1 thread per block and `n` blocks, so you'll need to have:

```
__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
  int i = blockDim.x;
  c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

... but try to **avoid** having few threads per block - your performance will be dismal that way. So please **don't** use the above code; rather, create a grid with large blocks.